# TextView and attribute not allowed here in android studio + Gradl sync faild, Basic fonctionality?

Tags: android

- I have this problem with android studio, the attributes in red color, and showing TextView and attributes---> not allowed here
- Gradl sync faild, Basic fonctionality : I use the offline mode and the default, the same problem.

[image]

Comment: add your grade files codes

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is currently set to offline mode, so Android studio can't download dependencies and resolve it.
*Go to Preferences -> Gradle then uncheck "Offline work".*

UPDATE:
Check this video [https://youtu.be/gsKoA1_3xX0] [1] 
Resync your project

Comment: I have made that, but the same